# Jquery width minus pixels compatible with IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, fluid-layout

I'm trying to use Jquery to calculate the width of my div minus a px gutter. I know this has been asked over and over again, but the answers I find are not IE compatible.

Therefore, CSS calc won't do. The code I'm using at the moment is:

```
$('.left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=40px');
```

But this also doesn't work on IE.

Ideas welcome!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.left').width(function() {
    return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.35) - 40;
});
```

a width of 100% means the element is as wide as it's parent, so just subtract 40px from that

Comment: Sorry, that was just for reference. It's actually 35%

Comment: @Alga - still the same, just multiply it with 0.35

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.left').css('width', '100%').width($('.left').width() - 40);
```

**EDIT:**
For more than one element:

```
$('.left').css('width', '100%').width(function(){
    return $(this).width() - 40;
});
```

Comment: that's involved all .left elements have the same width

Answer (score 0):

```
var $left = $('.left');
$left.css('width', '100%').width($left.width() - 40);
```